# Getting a single instance of an object

Tags: java

Let's say I have a class `A` and this class has a List `l`. There is also a class `B` that extends `A` that will access the list `l`, as shown below. In my program, there must only be an instance of the class `B` (I'm using Singleton pattern), and there must be only one instance of the List `l` also, so I'm doing it like this:

```
public abstract class A {

    protected List<String> l;

    public A() {}

    protected synchronized List<String> getList() {
        if (l == null)
            l = new LinkedList<String>();
        return l;
    }
}

//---

public class B extends A {

    private static B instance;

    private B() {
        super();
    }

    public static synchronized B getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
        instance = new B();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is:

In one instance of `B`:

```
System.out.println(super.getList().size()); //must print 0
super.getList().add("a");
System.out.println(super.getList().size()); //will print 1
```

In another instance of `B`:

```
System.out.println(super.getList().size()); //should print 1, cause i've already
                                            //added "a", but prints 0
super.getList().add("b");
System.out.println(super.getList().size()); //should print 2, but prints 1
```

That is not working as expected though. What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me?

---

EDITED:

Hi, Bill the Lizard, here are the two classes:

```
public abstract class A {
    protected static List<String> l;

    public A() {}

    protected static synchronized List<String> getList() {
        if (l == null)
            l = new LinkedList<String>();
        return l;
    }
}

//---

public class B extends A {
    private static B instance;

    private B() {
        super();
    }

    public static synchronized B getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new B();
        return instance;
    }

    public void metodo() {
        System.out.println(super.getList().size());
        super.getList().add("a");
        System.out.println(super.getList().size());
    }
}
```

And this is how i create an instance of B:

```
public class ClassTeste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = B.getInstance();
        b.metodo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the full code.  How are you creating two instances of `B`?

Comment: It's not a singleton if you can have two instances of B. Or did you mean "in another reference of B"?

Comment: I just edited my question, adding the details asked by Bill the Lizard.

Comment: It is still not clear how you created another instance. It now much more sounds like you've run the `main()` method two times in two subsequent JVM sessions and are expecting that JVM somehow magically serializes the instance to disk or so and revives/reuses it on next startup. If this is true, then the final answer would be: use a database (and learn Java a bit harder).

Comment: So I think I misexpressed myself and did the wrong thing to test it, BalusC. I want it to work like that in a multi-threaded application, where multiple objects will access that list l.

Comment: In a multi-threaded environment, you need to synchronize the 'add' and 'size' methods on the same lock object (probably your B singleton)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run your main revised code, with the following main method,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 B b1 = B.getInstance();
 b1.metodo();

 B b2 = B.getInstance();
 b2.metodo();
}
```

and got the following output, which matches what you're looking for

```
0
1
1
2
```

Comment: What I was trying to do is execute the main two times, barryred. I was using debug, and this is not the result i was expecting.
I was getting "0 1" in one execution, and "0 1" in the other.

Comment: If you run the main twice, you're going to have 2 VM instances, which means all static variables will disappear between one run and another.
You'll need to save the state of B to a file (or java.util.prefs.Preferences may be easier) between one instantiation and another.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a singleton if you have more than one instance of B. (You may have meant reference)

Why don't you just do:

```
public abstract class A {

    protected List l = new LinkedList();

    public A() {}

    protected List getList() {
        return l;
    }
}
```

'l' will only be instantiated when A is instantiated (i.e. when B is instantiated).

```
public class B extends A {

    private static B instance = new B();

    private B() {
        // Don't need this, implicitly use no-args super-constructor by default
        // super();
    }

    public static B getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

'instance' will only be instantiated when the class B is referenced for the first time, so you're probably fine there.

Comment: It's also way less confusing for `l` to be non-static

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me.

```
B b1 = B.getInstance();
B b2 = B.getInstance();

b1.metodo();
b2.metodo();
```

I'm getting the following output.

> 0
>   1
>   1
>   2

The call to `b1.metodo()` is printing the size of the empty list and the size after adding "a" once.  The call to `b2.metodo()` is printing the same size again, then the new size after adding "a" again.

Comment: Hi, Bill, the problem is that metodo() will be called concurrently by several objects. And what you've done is not the way I call that method.

Comment: @AntonioJunior: Oh, that makes more sense now.  You'll need to synchronize access to the List, not just where it's created but anywhere you add or remove objects to/from it, get its size, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The singleton only lives for the life of the program. And it is not shared between other instances of your program.

It sounds like you expect this to run once and get an output of 1, and it exits, then run again and get an output of 2. Or run two programs and get on to output 1, and the other to output 2.

This only works if you are using threads, not whole processes, and it will still reset each time you kill the process and start a new one.